# TypeError when calling resample() in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I haven't touched the code for a while until my whole block of code started giving me a headache for days. It used to work until the following challenge with `resample` surfaced.

Here is the error:

> File "C:\Users\JonesDavid\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5522, in resample `base=base, key=on, level=level)`
>
> File "C:\Users\JonesDavid\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 999, in resample `return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)`
>
> File "C:\Users\JonesDavid\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1116, in _get_resampler `"but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)`
>
> **TypeError**: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

- in doForecast: `tsWeekly = ts.resample('W-MON').last())`
- in main: `doForecast(panel)`
- in : `main()`

This is my entire code minus the plotting-related parts:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
# removed imports related to plotting

TRAIN_SIZE = 0.2
FORECAST_STEPS = 20
STOCKS_PREDICT = ['SPY', 'AAPL']


def downloadData(startDate, endDate):

    histPanel = web.DataReader(STOCKS_PREDICT, 'iex' , startDate, endDate)
    contains_condition = ((histPanel.isnull()) | (histPanel == 0)).any(axis=1)
    to_keep = contains_condition[contains_condition == False].index
    histPanel = histPanel.loc[to_keep]

    return histPanel


print(downloadData("01/01/2017","01/01/2019"))


def doForecast(Panel):

    closeDF = Panel['close']
    ts = closeDF['SPY']
    tsWeekly = ts.resample('W-MON').last() # TypeError here
    values = tsWeekly.tolist()
    
    # removed unrelevant plotting code


def main():
    startDate = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
    endDate = datetime.today()

    panel = downloadData(startDate, endDate)

    doForecast(panel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the whole error message. I'm talking about ""but got an instance of %r" part. Which, to me, looks like it was expecting a different type than `ax`. (That looks like the source code of the error that was thrown, so that's weird.)

Comment: Also, this doesn't look like your entire code since it mentions a `_get_resampler` function and a line 5522. Try to add all of the relevant parts of the code but also keep it minimal: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Dear @FurkanKambay I have just added the detailed error.

Comment: The error comes from here, but the version of `pandas` is different: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0d6cb3c21d1305d75878eee7a470bf463b6754bd/pandas/core/resample.py#L1312

Comment: The error is that the type of `ax` isn't supported which is what the error message says. I'm not familiar with `pandas` but the problem is either that your code messes with the `ax` property (which comes from the `groupby` argument in `Resampler`'s initializer which is a `TimeGrouper`. That's some info I gathered from looking at the source code but debugging would help - which we can't do from here.

Comment: The line `ts = closeDF['SPY']`. `ts` comes from `downloadData`. The function returns `histPanel` and `histPanel['close']['SPY']` is of type `Index` when it should be one of those 3 in the error message.

Comment: Thanks @FurkanKambay! Would debugging the resampler.py work?

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with `pandas`. It might just be a bug and it might have been fixed in a future version, so a version update might be all you need. Although if it's not a bug, the problem isn't in `resampler.py` or `generic.py` but in the `downloadData` function.

Comment: Do you have the latest versions of `pandas` and `pandas_datareader`? What versions?

Comment: Run `pip show pandas pandas-datareader | findstr "Version:"` in cmd or PowerShell to find out. It might help. Also, try the latest versions; maybe it was a bug and was fixed.

Comment: Hi I was trying to upgrade via pip but it seems like I'm facing the following error with Pip: You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command. I did uninstall and reinstalling as well. Could this be the problem?

Comment: That is just a pip issue, not relevant to your code. If you don't have a reason to keep the old version of pip or any of the packages, you should upgrade. First run that command to upgrade pip to 18.1, then upgrade the packages.

Comment: The problem is exactly like the error message states. The index of the DataFrame is not related to time; so how can any weekly resampling ever work? I vaguely remember running into something like this myself at one point, so it might very well be that the intrinsic behaviour changed at one point. Anyway, try running `import pandas as pd`; `panel.index = pd.to_datetime(panel.index)`

Comment: Thanks All for the help. Unfortunately as a last resort I re-coded some of the chunks that have been obsolete in order for it to work.